# How to deduce the structure of an EM wave

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, maxwell-equations

Suppose we have, in vacuum, the following electric field:

$$\vec{E}(z,t)=\sqrt{\frac{2\omega ^2}{\varepsilon _0 V}}q(t)\sin\left(kz\right)\hat{x} \tag{1}$$

in my lecture notes it is stated that then the magnetic field should be

$$\vec{B}(z,t)=\frac{1}{c^2k}\sqrt{\frac{2\omega ^2}{\varepsilon _0 V}}\dot{q}(t)\cos\left(kz\right)\hat{x} \tag{2}$$

creating a full EM wave.

**Ok, let's try to prove it:**

Maxwell's second equation

$$\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E}=-\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t} \tag{3}$$

leads to:

$$\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E}=\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E}_x(z)=\vec{\nabla} \times\left(\sqrt{\frac{2\omega ^2}{\varepsilon _0 V}}q(t)\sin\left(kz\right)\hat{x}\right) \tag{4}$$

if we remember the definition of curl in 3D:

$$\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{F} := \hat{x} \left (\frac {\partial F_z}{\partial y} - \frac {\partial F_y}{\partial z} \right ) + \hat{y} \left (\frac {\partial F_x}{\partial z} - \frac {\partial F_z}{\partial x} \right) + \hat{z} \left (\frac {\partial F_y}{\partial x} - \frac {\partial F_x}{\partial y} \right) \tag{5}$$

we get

$$\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E}=\vec{\nabla} \times \vec{E}_x(z)= \frac {\partial E_x}{\partial z} \hat{y}=k\sqrt{\frac{2\omega ^2}{\varepsilon _0 V}}q(t)\cos\left(kz\right)\hat{y} \tag{6}$$

and so by $(3)$:

$$\frac{\partial \vec{B}}{\partial t}=-k\sqrt{\frac{2\omega ^2}{\varepsilon _0 V}}q(t)\cos\left(kz\right)\hat{y} \tag{7}$$

$$\vec{B}=\left(-\int k\sqrt{\frac{2\omega ^2}{\varepsilon _0 V}}q(t)\cos\left(kz\right) dt\right)\hat{y} \tag{8}$$

so we get the correct direction: the magnetic field must be in the $y$ direction, **but** expression $(8)$ is **not** equal to expression $(2)$. What is going on? Have I made a mistake somewhere or are my lecture notes wrong?

Comment: Are you sure there is no typo? Generally, $E \propto \dot{ A}$ and $B \propto A$ in free space.

Comment: @MsTais I am not sure.. That's why I asked here

Comment: Well, the dims are wrong - first theorist's check.

Comment: The dimensions are correct, however the directions are inconsistent. Your lecture notes are wrong.

Comment: Have you tried using $\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{B}=c^{-2}\partial_t\vec{E}$ instead? (I've set $\vec{j}=\vec{0}$ because of the in-the-vacuum hint.) But the $\hat{x}$ in $\vec{B}$ should be $\hat{y}$.

Comment: (Once you've done that, you can verify $\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{E}+\partial_t\vec{B}=0$ provided $\ddot{q}=-(ck)^2q=-\omega^2q$.)